# Generating random numbers in a 3d Numpy array based on two points in that array as min and max range of the random numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d Numpy array (80, 150, 150), and for every layer (Z dimension), I wanted to generate random numbers between two fixed points (Point 1 and Point 2) in that array based on minimum and maximum of these two points in every layer (Z dimension). How can I efficiently do this in Python?

So far, I have the following code:

```
    Point_1 = my_np_array[:, 62, 62]   # fixed point for all layers
    Point_2 = my_np_array[:, 54, 98]   # fixed point for all layers
    
    
    for layer in my_np_array[layer, :, :]: 
        between_points_12 = np.zeros(80, (Point_2 - Point_1), (Point_2 - Point_1))
    
        for i in range(0,(Point_2 - Point_1)):   # Point_2 - Point 1 , I meant to show the number of points between these two points
            x = round(random.uniform(min(Point_1, Point_2), max(Point_1, Point_2)), 4)
            diag_points_12.append(x)
        
        print(diag_points_12.sort())
```

As a reproducible code, I tried the following which only generates 37 random numbers only for the last layer, whereas I am expecting it to generate 2969 (80 * 37) non zero random values

```
    my_np_array = np.arange(1800000).reshape(80, 150, 150)
    Point_1 = my_np_array[:, 62, 62]   # fixed point for all layers
    Point_2 = my_np_array[:, 54, 98]   # fixed point for all layers
    
    AA_b= [my_np_array[k,:,:] for k in range(80)]
    
    counter = 0
    for layer, index in enumerate(AA_b):
        print(layer)
        between_points_12 = np.zeros(2960).tolist()
    
        Mina = min(Point_1[layer], Point_2[layer])
        Maxa = max(Point_1[layer], Point_2[layer])
     
        # between_points_12 = np.zeros(2960, dtype = None).tolist()
        for i in range(0,37):   # 37 = (98 - 62)+1
            x = round(random.uniform(Mina, Maxa), 4)
            between_points_12.append(x)
        counter =+1

        print(between_points_12.sort())
```

Comment: can you please provide a minima reproducible example (input and output)?

Comment: @mozway I provided one, although it may not be complete